# can you set ContenetProvider programmatically in android ?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, programmatically-created

how to do this code programmatically?

```
 <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider1458576911068628"
            android:exported="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this programmatically. A ContentProvider is an app component, and the Android system needs to know it exists, and therefore, it must be listed in the manifest file. From [Android Application Fundamentals guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#Manifest):

> Before the Android system can start an app component, the system must
>   know that the component exists by reading the app's
>   AndroidManifest.xml file (the "manifest" file). Your app must declare
>   all its components in this file, which must be at the root of the app
>   project directory.

Comment: Thanks! I'll think of another solution.